# Creating an UL via drag and drop from Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create an unordered list (UL) in my div "#dropZone" if one doesn't already exist.

If one does exist, I would like to add the dragged item as an additional LI of the UL.

I have three sources to drag from:

- #drg1
- #drg2
- #grid - or would this be my #mRow?

Here is a JSFiddle link to my attempt:

[JSFiddle - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'](http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrilhall/nmB69/297/)

```
var drpOptions = {
group: "gridGroup",
drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($('#dropZone').has('ul')) {
        $("#list").append('<li>' + ui.draggable.text() + '</li>');
    } else {
        $("#dropZone").append('<ul id="list"><li>' + ui.draggable.text() + '</li></ul>');
    }
}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is not `draggable` but `kendoDraggable`. Check example of using in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/draggable#hint-function--jquery).

You might want to define a `hint` function like this:

```
$("#drg1").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone();
    }
});

$("#drg2").kendoDraggable({
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone();
    }
});
```

In order to see your `divs` *floating* around the page while you `drag` them.